# Creating tags in SVN with strange hierarchy

Tags: svn, tags

So, i've been working on a project for a long time and when I finally came to a release version and wanted to create a tag I suddenly realized, that the person, who set up the SVN server somehow didn't create trunk/branches/tags folders. So, the trunk is in the root folder of the SVN directory.

Is there any normal way I could create a tag?

Comment: Oh, about a guy, that set up the repository.. we fired him.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create a `trunk` directory, move everything else into it.  Then create a `tags` directory.  Done!

```
svn mkdir trunk
for file in *; do 
    if [ "$file" != "trunk" ]; then
        svn mv $file trunk/;
    fi;
done
svn ci -m "Move everything into a trunk directory"
svn mkdir tags
svn ci -m "Create a tags directory"
```

Comment: Pretty obvious solution... well, thanx =) That would mess up local copies, but that's ok.